# Why is blue ink looking as white in this video?

Tags: optics, visible-light

[image: Snip]

[Video Link](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/linear-algebra-machine-learning/introduction-einstein-summation-convention-and-the-symmetry-of-the-dot-product-kI0DB)

In the video, when the presenter writes on the transparent board using a blue marker (beginning at 0:40) the text appears to be white and not blue. When he writes with the other markers, the text appears to the same colour as of the marker colour (yellow marker at 1:20, one can see the red colour at 1:40 as well). Also, notice that the tip of the marker is still blue.

Why is only the blue colour ink showing white? I guess this has to do something with the blue background. Intuitively, I think that the blue colour of the marker would be enhanced by the blue background and the text would appear bluer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that all of these colors show up as intended, with all colors being quite pastel.  However, if you suspect that the ink is bluer than is represented by the screen or camera, the culprit is very likely automatic white balancing.  Since the environment is blue, it is possible that the camera has attempted to white balance (using the shirt as a reference, for example) such that all colors in the scene are reduced in their blue value, such that the shirt appears white.  If we were to compare to another scene in which the room were white, we would observe that the shirt in the blue room was bluer.  Without this external white value reference, the compensation whitens the shirt but reduces the saturation of the blue marker.